# What's the difference of $xRy=1$ on $\mathbb {Z}$ or $\mathbb {R}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose we define the relation xRy iff xy=1, is this relation:

Reflexive?

Irreflexive?

Symmetric?

Antisymmtric?

Transitive?

From my understanding on Z (integers), the relation is symmetric and transitive.

**Symmetric**: if xy=1 then yx=1 is true

**Transitive**: if xy=1 then yz=1, so xz=1

**Neither Reflexive or irreflexive**: xx=1 iff x=1, so there is at least one instance, not all instances, where xRx, so it's neither (if I am applying this correctly - it's reflexive if xx=1 for all x, and irreflexive if xx!=1 for all x)

However, what's the difference between asking if this is on the Real (R) set or the integer set (Z)?  Are they the same?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflexive: Fails in both Integers and Reals.

Symmetic: Passes in both Integers and Reals.

Transitive: Passes in Integers *but* fails in Reals.

We can write the relation as $R_A=\{(x,x^{-1}): x\in A\}$ where $A$ is either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$.   As you noticed, when under the Integers, the relation is $R_{\Bbb Z}=\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$ as only $1$ and $-1$ have multiplicative inverse (which are themselves) and this trivially transitive.   However, in the Reals there are *many* more entries in $R_\Bbb R$, which preserves symmetry but breaks transitivity [because if $xy=1\wedge yz=1$ then $x=z$, but $xx=1$ only if $x=\pm 1$].

Answer (score 1):

There’s a big difference between doing this for real numbers vs integers. For one thing, in the integers $xRy\Rightarrow x=y$,  which isn’t true for te real numbers. We have $2R0.5$, $0.5R2$, but not $2R2$ so for the reals it is not transitive.

You have the right answers but the wrong analysis for the integers. In addition to $1R1$ there is also $-1R-1$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you for that.  Is my application of the integers correct though?

Comment: @Slurpee I’ve edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. When you extend the set, you could never be guaranteed to keep the property of a relation. It's possible to keep the property only when the extension is somewhat natural and compatible with the property by which you defined the relation.

In this case, when you consider in $R$, the transitivity is broken, (you can easily notice that.)